# Why are the declensions numbered as they are?

Tags: terminology

I thought I read somewhere that the declensions are numbered First through Fifth according to a vowel in one of the endings, the numbers corresponding to the sequence of vowels in the alphabet: a, e, i, o, u. But I can't remember where or exactly what the rationale was.

Is the numbering of the declensions arbitrary or does it have a rationale?

Comment: Hi Ben, I believe the above links answer your question already.

Comment: @cmw Well, how about that! An answer to my question is in the middle of [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/17794/118). Very interesting!

Comment: I wonder if you read that before and just forgot. I know that happens to me!

Comment: @cmw I think I was thrown by the title, emphasizing who numbered them rather than the basis of the numbers. I hadn't noticed until today that the answer also answers my question.